# Keep ul li elements centered even when resizing down to one or more lines

Tags: html, css, list, responsive-design

I have a list that I need to be responsive in my footer.

e.g:

```
<ul>
     <li>About</li>
     <li>Contact</li>
     <li>Company Information</li>
     <li>Contact Us / Help</li>
</ul>
```

What I need to do is have that ul in the footer so that the items are centered across multiple lines.

So it will look like:

```
About    Contact    Company Information    Contact Us / Help
```

Then on a mobile device etc:

```
                    About    Contact

        Company Information    Contact Us / Help
```

But I cannot think how.

CSS is for now just a basic horizontal list... jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cgke4hvu/

If you resize the preview on that fiddle hopefully you will see what I require.

Thanks.

Comment: You're most likely looking at flexbox to help you out ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove `float: left` and use this CSS:

```
body {
    width: 100%;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    border: 1px solid blue;   /* added just for clearer view */
    text-align: center; /* added */
}

ul li {
    display: inline;  /* added */
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

try the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cgke4hvu/2/)

Comment: Lovely thanks, had to go with inline-block on the li for my project but now working.

Comment: I think inline-block shoul work too. Cannot test it cause i turned of my laptop. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](https://jsfiddle.net/cgke4hvu/1) way - the easiest. Just set `.clear` class to every `li` which you want see in new line.

```css
body {
    width: 100%;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

ul li {
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .clear {
        clear: left;
    }   
}
```

```html
 <ul>
     <li>About</li>
     <li>Contact</li>
     <li class="clear">Company Information</li>
     <li>Contact Us / Help</li>
</ul>
```